# Bootstrap align text vertically to switch button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align a text in a `<label>` or `<span>` element to this custom switch button:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>Custom switch</span>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I cannot get it working setting the `margin` or `float` on the `switch` class element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>Custom switch</span>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Flex is the best option indeed

Comment: this works, but it may lead to errors when in a `input-group` that is `inline` like a `form-inline` or a `inline-table` display mode. How to combine them?

Comment: @loretoparisi can you share an example of it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/updcx1Lo/ actually it works here, the problem I think was some custom CSS I had elsewhere!

Comment: @loretoparisi you can group the items in a separate div element and give style to that element instead of giving flex style to the body

Answer (score 1):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.right-div {
display: inline-block;
}
.left-div {
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.parent-div{
display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="left-div">
    <span>Custom switch</span>
   </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
   </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to flex, you can also use css tables:

```css
.switch-container {
  display: table;
}

.switch-label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
  <span class="switch-label">Custom switch</span>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added a `float: left` to the `.switch-container` in order to align inline items.

Comment: `float: left` shouldn't break the `display: table` attribute.